# How to call ReactJS function with event (event.ctrlKey)?

Tags: reactjs, events, key

I have a code similar to this one:

```
function Component1(...) {
...
   function checkIfCtrlKey(event) {
     return event.ctrlKey;
   }
   return (
     { checkIfCtrlKey() && (<Component2 .../>) }
   );
}
```

The sense behind this is that the Component2 is just rendered if the Ctrl-key is being pressed. When running this code, I get following error message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'ctrlKey' of undefined

What is my mistake? Is there a solution or other possibility to implement my need?

Answer (score 0):

Your making mistake here,

```
{ checkIfCtrlKey() && (<Component2 .../>) }
```

refer

```
function checkIfCtrlKey(event) {
     return event.ctrlKey;
   }
```

How u suppose that `checkIfCtrlKey` will be passed with event arg when your calling like this `checkIfCtrlKey()` ??

You might wanted to attach it to window,

```
function Component1() {
  const [ctrlKeyPressed, setCKP] = useState(false)

  const handleKey = ev => {
    setCKP(ev.ctrlKey)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKey);
    window.addEventListener('keyup', handleKey);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKey);
      window.removeEventListener('keyup', handleKey);
    }
  }, [])

  return  (
    <>
      ...
      {ctrlKeyPressed && <Component2 />}
      ...
    </>
  )
}
```

Shows `Component2` as long as `ctrlKey` is pressed

Comment: @The1NOnly pls, mark as answer & upvote if it helped

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vanilla JS for that like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [ctrlPressed, setCtrlPressed] = useState(false);
  const handleKey = (e) => setCtrlPressed(e.ctrlKey);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKey);
    window.addEventListener("keyup", handleKey);

    return function cleanup() {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKey);
      window.removeEventListener("keyup", handleKey);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {ctrlPressed ? <h2>You're pressing CTRL Key</h2> : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Working example [over here](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-albattani-ef536?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put an `event` listener on the `window` object and within that hander you can set some `state` to switch between a `true` and `false`

Something like this.

```
function Component1() {

const [ctrlActive, setCtrlActive] = useState(false) 

useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', (e => {
        if("Do a check here to see if it's CTRL key") {
          setCtrlActive(!ctrlActive)  
        }
    }), [])    
})
return ctrlActive ? <Component2 /> : null
```

}